# Query current power config settings on Windows 7

Tags: windows, power-management

Powercfg gives the ability to set certain settings like `monitor-timeout-ac` and `standby-timeout-dc` using `powercfg -change <setting> <value>`. Is it possible to query the current values of those settings? I looked through the help text but I did not see a way through the `powercfg` command. Perhaps there is another command that can provide the current state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To query specific sections regarding the specific settings you mention do similar to the following:

- `powercfg -list` to get a list of current power plan GUIDs.  Note/Copy the GUID for the plan you want to query.
- `powercfg -aliases` to get a list GUIDs for plan sub-sections.  Note/Copy the GUIDs for "SUB_SLEEP" and "SUB_VIDEO".
- `powercfg -query <GUID of power plan> <GUID of sub-section>`.

Example output of "SUB-SLEEP" subsection:

```
C:\Windows\system32>powercfg -query 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20

Power Scheme GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c  (High performance)
  Subgroup GUID: 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20  (Sleep)
    Power Setting GUID: 29f6c1db-86da-48c5-9fdb-f2b67b1f44da  (Sleep after)
      Minimum Possible Setting: 0x00000000
      Maximum Possible Setting: 0xffffffff
      Possible Settings increment: 0x00000001
      Possible Settings units: Seconds
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000

    Power Setting GUID: 94ac6d29-73ce-41a6-809f-6363ba21b47e  (Allow hybrid sleep)
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Off
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: On
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001

    Power Setting GUID: 9d7815a6-7ee4-497e-8888-515a05f02364  (Hibernate after)
      Minimum Possible Setting: 0x00000000
      Maximum Possible Setting: 0xffffffff
      Possible Settings increment: 0x00000001
      Possible Settings units: Seconds
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000

    Power Setting GUID: bd3b718a-0680-4d9d-8ab2-e1d2b4ac806d  (Allow wake timers)
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Disable
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Enable
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001
```

Example of "SUB_VIDEO" secion:

```
C:\Windows\system32>powercfg -query 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c 7516b95
f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99

Power Scheme GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c  (High performance)
  Subgroup GUID: 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99  (Display)
    Power Setting GUID: 17aaa29b-8b43-4b94-aafe-35f64daaf1ee  (Dim display after)
      Minimum Possible Setting: 0x00000000
      Maximum Possible Setting: 0xffffffff
      Possible Settings increment: 0x00000001
      Possible Settings units: Seconds
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000258
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x0000012c

    Power Setting GUID: 3c0bc021-c8a8-4e07-a973-6b14cbcb2b7e  (Turn off display after)
      Minimum Possible Setting: 0x00000000
      Maximum Possible Setting: 0xffffffff
      Possible Settings increment: 0x00000001
      Possible Settings units: Seconds
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000384
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000258

    Power Setting GUID: aded5e82-b909-4619-9949-f5d71dac0bcb  (Display brightness)
      Minimum Possible Setting: 0x00000000
      Maximum Possible Setting: 0x00000064
      Possible Settings increment: 0x00000001
      Possible Settings units: %
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000064
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000064

    Power Setting GUID: f1fbfde2-a960-4165-9f88-50667911ce96  (Dimmed display brightness)
      Minimum Possible Setting: 0x00000000
      Maximum Possible Setting: 0x00000064
      Possible Settings increment: 0x00000001
      Possible Settings units: %
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x0000001e
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x0000001e
```

Comment: I guess I am going to have to parse the output myself. I would like just the number of seconds in base 10, I assume there isn't a simple way to get just that?

Comment: You asked for an answer kind of specific to Powercfg.  If you need something more scriptable, look into [using Powershell for that](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/08/31/get-windows-power-plan-settings-on-your-computer-by-using-powershell.aspx). :)

Comment: I guess I did. I just wrote a quick regex to get what I needed out of the query.

Comment: Do You know how to interpret those hex values? I changed `SUB-SLEEP/sleep after` from 0 to 5, but the hex value changed from `0x0000` to `0x0012`, which is 18 in decimal. What is going on here? The official documentation does not say a word how to read the output.

Comment: Got the end of it - windows stores the time values in `seconds`, however the `/change` command expects `minutes`. Because windows like consistency.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on @randy's excellent answer, but I thought I wold add a small bit to the end for those wanting just the times in decimal format:

```
#Show Current Settings
$sleeptime = [uint32]"$sleepSettingTrimmed"
$hibtime = [uint32]"$hibernateSettingTrimmed"

if($sleepSettingTrimmed -eq "0x00000000")
{
Write-Host "Sleep is currently disabled on AC."
}
else
{
write-host "Time to Sleep on AC is currently $sleeptime seconds."
}

if($hibernateSettingTrimmed -eq "0x00000000")
{
Write-Host "Hibernation is currently disabled on AC."
}
else
{
write-host "Time to Hibernate on AC is currently $hibtime seconds."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Surprisingly enough it is using the following setting:

```
powercfg -query
```

Here's an excerpt of the command `powercfg -? |more`:

```
POWERCFG <command line options>
Description:
  This command line tool enables users to control the power settings
  on a system.

Parameter List:
  -LIST, -L   Lists all power schemes in the current user's environment.

          Usage: POWERCFG -LIST

  -QUERY, -Q  Displays the contents of the specified power scheme.

          Usage: POWERCFG -QUERY <SCHEME_GUID> <SUB_GUID>

          <SCHEME_GUID>  (optional) Specifies the GUID of the power scheme
                         to display, can be obtained by using powercfg -l.
          <SUB_GUID>     (optional) Specifies the GUID of the subgroup
                         to display.  Requires a SCHEME_GUID to be provided.

          If neither SCHEME_GUID or SUB_GUID are provided, the settings
          of the current user's active power scheme are displayed.
          If SUB_GUID is not specified, all settings in the specified
          power scheme are displayed.
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but there was no answer that met my needs. After much searching and playing around with the output, I came up with the following script to meet my needs. It gets the time to sleep (while on AC power - plugged in) and time to hibernate (while on AC power - plugged in) and returns both of them. I needed these values for my scenario, but you can look at the output of `$options` and use this code as a template to get whatever other data you may need:

```
#Get GUID of active plan
$GUID = (((Get-CimInstance -classname Win32_PowerPlan -Namespace "root\cimv2\power" | where {$_.IsActive -eq "true"}).InstanceID) -split("\\"))[1]
#Cut {} off of string at beginning and end of GUID
$GUID = $GUID.Substring(1, $GUID.Length-2)

#Get a list of all options for this plan
$Options = powercfg -query $GUID
$index = 0

#Find index of line that contains Sleep Settings
For($i=0; $i -lt $Options.Length; $i++)
{
    $line = $Options[$i]
    if($line.ToLower() -like "*sleep after*")
    {
        $index = $i
        break
    }        
}

#AC Setting is 6 lines later
$sleepSetting = $Options[$index + 6]
#trim off the beginning of the string, leaving only the value
$sleepSettingTrimmed = $sleepSetting.Substring($sleepSetting.IndexOf(":")+2)

#output should now be "0x00000000" if off, or another number representing minutes

#Find index of line that contains Hibernate Settings
For($i=0; $i -lt $Options.Length; $i++)
{
    $line = $Options[$i]
    if($line.ToLower() -like "*hibernate after*")
    {
        $index = $i
        break
    }        
}

#AC Setting is 6 lines later
$hibernateSetting = $Options[$index + 6]
#trim off the beginning of the string, leaving only the value
$hibernateSettingTrimmed = $hibernateSetting.Substring($hibernateSetting.IndexOf(":")+2)

echo "$sleepSettingTrimmed $hibernateSettingTrimmed"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# get current power sleep time setting
# I know of no other way to return the single number of the sleep time
# (powershell)
# run script with "powershell -file" to get errorlevel set right

# (Balanced plan) (Sleep section)
# can't do (Sleep after subsection guid) too?
$result = powercfg -query 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20

# line 8, 7th word, in hex, cast to decimal
[int64]$sleeptime = ($result[7] -split ("\s+"))[6]

# return sleep time in minutes in errorlevel
exit $sleeptime/60
```